# ColorBox over Flash in Firefox, Vista

Tags: jquery, flash, windows-vista, colorbox

I am using ColorBox over a Flash file which works just fine in all browsers on all platforms except for an annoying behaviour in Firefox on Vista. On calling ColorBox it pops up and displays the loading graphic fine, but once the content has loaded the ColorBox window resizes and then stalls for up to 10 seconds before showing the content, see screen grab. It shows the ColorBox window in a state before and after it has been resized at the same time for up to 10 seconds and then displays the content.

However, I did notice when trying to screen grab this behaviour that hitting Print Screen seemed to force the content to show. I could not get ColorBox to remain in this state after hitting the Print Screen button on my keyboard.

Any ideas?

[alt text http://tinyurl.com/ylcpdzb](http://tinyurl.com/ylcpdzb)

Answer (score 0):

Does any of this help?

http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/d21f8ab64d366117/a5f56ae4b61797af

Specifically changing visibility to hidden using Colorbox OnLoad and OnClosed? Just about to experiment myself with Colorbox over flash.